# Wifi: setting wireless region / registration domain

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, command-line

I'm unable to change the registration domain of my wireless adapter. I'm using the `iw reg set/get` command but only the `global` country gets the new value. The `phy#0` stays with `US`.

```
root@ccimx6ulsbc:~# iw reg get
global
country US: DFS-FCC
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
phy#0
country US: DFS-FCC
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

root@ccimx6ulsbc:~# iw reg set JP
root@ccimx6ulsbc:~# iw reg get
global
country JP: DFS-JP
        (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM
        (4910 - 4990 @ 40), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
        (5030 - 5090 @ 40), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
        (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
        (59000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 10), (N/A)
phy#0
country US: DFS-FCC
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
        (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but recently I've seen several Wi-Fi device manufacturers having separate "US" and "International" versions of their hardware, with the US version being factory-locked to FCC regulatory rules only. If you have bought the adapter from a US store, it is possible that its firmware was deliberately made to refuse these changes.

Comment: I'm working with a development board for an iMX6 (https://www.digi.com/products/models/cc-sbp-wmx-jn58)